# Segmentation Fault 11 when trying to read an image byte per byte

Tags: c, image, file, segmentation-fault, fopen

Im trying to write a simple C code that counts how many times a byte is repeated in a file. We tried the code with .txt files and works wonders (max size tested: 137MB). But when we tried it with an image (even small, 2KB) it returned **Segmentation Fault 11**.

I've done some research and found some specific libs for images, but I don't want to resort to them since the code it's not only meant for images, but for virtually any type of file. Is there a way to simple read a file byte per byte regardless of anything else (extension, meta, etc).

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *f;
    char *file;
    long numTotalBytes = 0;
    int bytesCount[256] = {0}; 

    f = fopen ( argv[1], "rb");
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    numTotalBytes = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    file = calloc(1, numTotalBytes);    
    fread(file, numTotalBytes, 1, f);
    fclose(f);

        printf("numTotalBytes: %ld", numTotalBytes); //<- this gives the right output even for images

    unsigned int i;
    for (i=0; i<numTotalBytes; ++i) {
        unsigned char pointer = file[i]; //<- This access fails at file[1099]
        int pointer_int = (int)pointer;
        printf("iteration %i with pointer at %i\n", i, pointer_int); //<- pointer_int is never below 0 or above 255
        //++bytesCount[(int)file[i]];
        ++bytesCount[pointer_int];
    }

    free(file);
}
```

Some extra info:
 - Changing the extension of the img to .txt doesn't work.
 - The code returns Segmentation Fault exactly at iteration 1099 (file I'm using is aprox 163KB so file[i] should accept accesses up to aprox file[163000]).
 - For txt files works perfect. Reads the bytes one by one and counts them as expected, regardless of file size.
 - I'm on Mac (you never know...)

//EDIT: I have edited the code for a more desglosed and explanatory one because some of you where telling me things I've already tried.

//EDIT_2: Ok guys, never mind. This version should work in any other computer that its not mine. I think the problem is with my terminal when passing arguments but I just switched OS and it works.

Comment: the extension really doesn't mean anything...

Comment: Try changing `(int)` to `(unsigned)`. You don't want negative indexes.

Comment: `fseek()` and `ftell()` is not a good way to calculate size of files. [FIO19-C. Do not use fseek() and ftell() to compute the size of a regular file - CERT C Coding Standard - CERT Secure Coding Standards](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek()+and+ftell()+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file)

Comment: You are mixing `long` with `int` for your byte count and loops, while `calloc` and `fread` take type `size_t`. Best to use `long` as that is what `ftell` returns.

Comment: Re the edit, you still have `char *file;` which should be `unsigned char *file;`

Answer (score 4):

- Do check if `fopen()` and `calloc()` are successful.
- The format specifier to print `long` is `%ld`, not `%lu`.
- `(int)file[i]` is bad for array index because converting `char` to `int` will preserve its value if all values that can be represented as `char` are representable in `int`, and because if `char` is signed in your environment (and setting), it may access negative index, cause out-of-range access and invoke *undefined behavior*.

You should change `++bytesCount[(int)file[i]];` to `++bytesCount[(unsigned char)file[i]];` in order to prevent using negative index.

Also note that `ftell()` with `SEEK_END` may note be supported for binary stream ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.21.9.2 The fseek function), so it is better to read one-by-one using `fgetc()` in order to avoid [undefined behavior](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek()+and+ftell()+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file) and to use less memory.

Comment: - Original code has checks for fopen and calloc already, I just put a smaller version in here. 
- Changed the %lu to %ld (thanks!). 
- Access to bytesCount works well, I've done a lot of debugging, splite the code line into two, with a lot of prints, casts to int, unsigned int, unsigned char, etc. They sometimes prints negative numbers if I dont use unsigned (as expected) but the access work well anyway. It's the acces to file[i] the one causing segmentation fault. The other never access anything below 0 or over 255. I may put the desglosed code if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

MikeCAT just beat me to it.  A bit more explanation follows, in case it helps.

To fix: change `file` to `unsigned char *file` and the increment to `++bytesCount[file[i]];`.

Exaplanation: per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/2877364), a plain `char` may be `signed` or `unsigned`.  In this case, I'm guessing it defaults to `signed`.  That means any value `>=0x80` will become a negative number.  Such values are not likely to be in your English-language text file, but are very likely to be in an image!  The typecast to `(int)` will keep negatives negative.  Therefore, the code will index `byteCounts` with a negative number, leading to the segmentation fault.

Comment: `0x80` may also be converted to a negative number.

Comment: Edited the original post for a better explanation. Its not the bytesCount[index] the one failing but the file[index] access causing segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by this line

```
++bytesCount[(int)file[i]];
```

The `bytesCount` is array of 256 ints. If `file[i]` is more than 256, you are accessing invalid memory and that can cause segmentation fault.

Comment: Edited the original post for a better explanation. Its not the bytesCount[index] the one failing but the file[index] access causing segmentation fault.